# ¿Como cambiar el idioma a español del plugin Select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2

Me gustaría saber como podría cambiar el idioma del select2, en el momento cuando no encuentra resultados me muestra este mensaje.

[image: No matches found]

https://select2.github.io/ ... esta es la pagina del plugin pero por el momento no he encontrado algo que me muestre de manera clara como hacerlo.
Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Alan, por favor utiliza [**esta guía**](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que reescribas tu pregunta de modo que se ajuste a los estándares de calidad de Stackoverflow en español.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la corrección, leeré la guía y tratare de mejorar la pregunta, soy nuevo en este tipo de foros

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer de dos formas:

Pasar los parámetros que deseas directamente a la función de `select2`:

```js
$('select').select2({    
  language: {

    noResults: function() {

      return "No hay resultado";        
    },
    searching: function() {

      return "Buscando..";
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>   

  
<select style="width:200px;" class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

o usar la librería de idiomas en tu caso en español:

```js
$.fn.select2.defaults.set('language', 'es');

$('select').select2();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<!-- Libreria español -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/i18n/es.js"></script>
  
<select style="width:200px;" class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Recuerda que tienes que poner la función del cambio de idiomas antes que inicies `select2`

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias, es justo lo que necesitaba

Answer (score 1):

Despues de cargar la libreria en español puedes poner la seudo etiqueta lang="es"

```
<!-- Libreria español -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/i18n/es.js"></script>  

<select style="width:200px;" class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple" lang="es">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```